# Filling out form with Requests and retrieve info

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am extremely new to Python and this is practically my first app, so please bear with me.  I would like to go to a specific website and fill out the information in the form and get whatever the info would be after `POST`ing the form. Could someone please help me with this.  Thank you in advance.

```
import requests
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# set needed variables
br = mechanize.Browser()
url = 'https://www.oanda.com/currency/average'
startMonth = input('Enter Month Number: ')
endMonth = startMonth
year = input('Enter Year: ')
duration = 'Month'
convertAmount = 1
foreignCurrency = 'AED'
domesticCurrency = 'USD'
interBankRate = 0
viewFormat = 'HTML'

payload = { 'amount': convertAmount, 'avg_type': duration,
            'start_month': startMonth, 'end_month': endMonth,
            'start_year': year, 'end_year': year, 'base': foreignCurrency,
            'exchange': domesticCurrency, 'interbank': interBankRate,
            'format': viewFormat }


#br.open(url)
#html = br.read()
#print html

# r = requests.get(url)
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
r.text
print r.text
```